# Can a subclass ovveride a concrete method and declare it abstract?

Tags: inheritance, overriding, abstract

This doesn't give a compile-time error. So this can be considered an override?

```
public class ClassA{

       public void metod(){
       }
}

public abstract class ClassB extends ClassA{

      @Override
      public abstract void metod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

A subclass can override a concrete method and declare it abstract. However, The subclass is now abstract (because it has at least one abstract method), and the subclass can not be instantiated again. It will need to be inherited again for it to be much useful. Its subclass in turn will re-implement the `metod` method for this latest subclass to be instantiatable.